# Adding external documents to Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are using report manager to create excel files. I need these files to appear in a Document Library.

I've mapped a drive to the Library. As a test I've tranasfered from desktops to Document Library using `http://mysharepoint/myLibrary`.

I've now tried creating a mapped drive on the server that runs Report Manager but the connection fails. Its because the server is not running Webdav. IT will not install Webdav service as it has too many overheads.

The other problem was that I could not attach metadata using the above approach.

Is there a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable incoming email to a document library and set up the reports on a scheduled execution and to send an email to the document library and include the Excel file as an attachment. If you give the various reports a specific subject, you might be able to use a workflow to then update metadata. If the reports are all executed about the same time, then someone could update them manually at that time.

Comment: Is it possible to group all emails/documents into created month? So the user does not need to wade through the entire document library? I know about the group feature in view but dont think this groups by month/year. Thanks

Comment: You could create 2 calculated columns, one that generates the year from the created date and one for the month and then use those columns to group on.